# Resolve error in Excel file after exporting

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a function to export my GridViews to Excel as .xlsx.  However I face a problem with the Excel file that was opened/saved with a save up dialogue. **The error happens when I try to open the Excel file:**

My current code:

```
  protected void EXPORT_BUTTON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            // creating new WorkBook within Excel application
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            String DATA1 = "DATA 1";
            String DATA2 = "DATA 2";
            ExportToExcel(app, workbook, DATA1 , DATA_1 );
            workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Delete();
            workbook.Worksheets["Sheet2"].Delete();
            workbook.Worksheets["Sheet3"].Delete();
            ExportToExcel(app, workbook, DATA2 , DATA_2);
            workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\testacc\Desktop\Test\" + "Server_" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            var filename = "Report_" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx";
            workbook.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Exports/") + filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment, filename=" + filename);
            workbook.Close();
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Exports/") + filename);
            app.Quit();
        }
```

Comment: this could be caused due to non proper closing of excel file without saving changes or sudden shut down

Comment: currently im using workbook.close() for my Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Exports/") + filename); to work. Please advice how can I change my codes to close the workbook thanks

Comment: well I do not remember the actual codes, but what I can suggest you is try closing the application as well

Comment: do you want to save the file to specific folder or just download it?

Comment: I tried app.Quit(); before response.ContentType ... but I still receive the same error.

Comment: there are 2 ways I want to do it. first it will save the file to a specific folder, secondly to allow user to save the folder to the desired folder thus there will be 2 files generated in each export. thanks @shreesha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code, if it works.

```
protected void EXPORT_BUTTON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application())
            // creating new WorkBook within Excel application
             using(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing))
             {
                String DATA1 = "DATA 1";
                String DATA2 = "DATA 2";
                ExportToExcel(app, workbook, DATA1 , DATA_1 );
                workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Delete();
                workbook.Worksheets["Sheet2"].Delete();
                workbook.Worksheets["Sheet3"].Delete();
                ExportToExcel(app, workbook, DATA2 , DATA_2);
                workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\testacc\Desktop\Test\" + "Server_" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                var filename = "Report_" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx";
                workbook.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Exports/") + filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment, filename=" + filename);
                workbook.Close();
                Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Exports/") + filename);
                Response.End();
                app.Quit();
            }
        }
```